# how to create url from an api in json

Tags: javascript, api

i have this api, and i need to create url from what i get from json

https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list

```
{"message":["affenpinscher","african","airedale","akita","appenzeller","australian","basenji","beagle","bluetick","borzoi","bouvier","boxer","brabancon","briard","buhund","bulldog","bullterrier","cattledog","chihuahua","chow","clumber","cockapoo","collie","coonhound","corgi","cotondetulear","dachshund","dalmatian","dane","deerhound","dhole","dingo","doberman","elkhound","entlebucher","eskimo","finnish","frise","germanshepherd","greyhound","groenendael","havanese","hound","husky","keeshond","kelpie","komondor","kuvasz","labradoodle","labrador","leonberg","lhasa","malamute","malinois","maltese","mastiff","mexicanhairless","mix","mountain","newfoundland","otterhound","ovcharka","papillon","pekinese","pembroke","pinscher","pitbull","pointer","pomeranian","poodle","pug","puggle","pyrenees","redbone","retriever","ridgeback","rottweiler","saluki","samoyed","schipperke","schnauzer","setter","sheepdog","shiba","shihtzu","spaniel","springer","stbernard","terrier","tervuren","vizsla","waterdog","weimaraner","whippet","wolfhound"],"status":"success"}
```

and what I need is that, URLs must be like this for each breed

'https://dog.ceo/api/breed/{breed name}/images';

Comment: Hi Lucas. What stops you from trying to create this? **Loops** and **string interpolation** are some of the basics of JavaScript. Be sure to research these aforementioned topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like Emiel said , these are basics of javaScript , keep your spirit and learn more
i give u simple example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>

<p>Multiply every element in the array with 10:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
const object ={"message":["affenpinscher","african","airedale","akita","appenzeller","australian"]}
const newArr = numbers.map(myFunction);
const newArrURL = object.message.map(myUrlFunction);


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = newArr;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = newArrURL;
function myFunction(num) {
  return num * 10;
}

function myUrlFunction(url) {
  return 'https://dog.ceo/api/breed/'+url+'/images';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the base url you have there and use string replace function to fill in place holder with the bird breed. Something like this:

```
const base_url = "https://dog.ceo/api/breed/{breed}/images"

const make_breed_url = (breed) => {
    return base_url.replace("{breed}", breed)
}
```

You could then call

```
make_breed_url("affenpinscher")
```

which would return

```
"https://dog.ceo/api/breed/affenpinscher/images"
```